# Missing setting.jar when importing a project to Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle

It was telling me that the module is not backed by Gradle and that it lacks a setting.jar file

Comment: Hi. Can you please [edit] your question to include more detail as *what* told you something? What was the actual message? Did you solve your problem with your answer or not because it is not a complete sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I created other project and copy and pasted the setting.gradle file to the folder and then it